Access query: compare records in a group then select one based on a criteria in another field
I've an Access query as shown below & I want to generate the yellow highlighted fields 
Description: 
For ItemID there are group(s) and a single duration, for each group there are days before and days after. 
The target (3 conditions): 
1- If a group elements has full duration i.e. (Full_Dur) flag is Yes for both, the required 2 fields (D_before_G & D_after_G) shall be same as D_before & D_after as in group "2". 

2-If a group elements has one full duration & the other is less the duration i.e. one (Full_Dur) flag is Yes & the second is No, the required 2 fields (D_before_G & D_after_G) shall be same as D_before & D_after with flag "No" as in group "1" ItemID "2010". 

3- If a group elements has less than full duration i.e. (Full_Dur) flag is No for both, the required 2 fields (D_before_G & D_after_G) shall be same as lowest D_before & the lowest D_after. 

Notes: 
Group elements are only 2 numbers & also not repeated within an "ItemID"
Fields D_before, D_after & Full_dur are calculated fields in a query. 



ID
ItemID
Group
Duration
D_before
D_after
Full_dur
D_before_G
D_after_G




1
2010
1
65
65
0
Yes
15
19


1
2010
1
65
15
19
No
15
19


1
2010
2
65
65
0
Yes
65
0


1
2010
2
65
65
0
Yes
65
0


1
2010
3
65
0
0
No
0
0


1
2010
3
65
0
0
No
0
0


2
1040
1
100
100
0
Yes
100
0


2
1040
1
100
100
0
Yes
100
0





Please insert the data table and results as formatted text. See Table for help.

@ShahramAlemzadeh I made the table & its preview is perfect while editing, but after saving the edit it didn't display properly !!

Calculating a value based on data in another record is not simple in Access. See example at http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord. Your situation has additional complication because need to pull multiple values. First, have to check value of Full_dur in other record to determine whether to pull D_before_G and D_after_G from another record. This is complicated enough that a custom VBA function may be needed. When you have code with issue, post question.

Example data for criteria 3 is same for both records. Is it possible for different values? If so, that would make better sample.

@June7 yes, it is possible for different values, the given sample (group 3) is infected by another parameter "Availability" (not shown) for this group, means this group can't be used.

You can solve this with two queries.
The first query is a GROUP BY-query finding the lowest value for Full_dur field. I.e. if there is a No-record it will return "No" otherwise it return "Yes" as Field YesOrNo.
In the second query you make two Dlockup() for the values in D_before and D_after filtering on ID, ItemID, Group and the YesOrNo field from the first query.
The main querys name in this example is qryData.
The first query (qryDataFindNo) looks like this:

The second query looks like this:

DLookups:
D_before_G: DLookUp("D_before","qryData","ID=" & [qryData].[ID] & " AND ItemID=" & [qryData].[ItemID] & " AND Group=" & [qrydata].[Group] & " AND Full_dur=""" & [YesOrNo] & """")
D_after_G: DLookUp("D_after","qryData","ID=" & [qryData].[ID] & " AND ItemID=" & [qryData].[ItemID] & " AND Group=" & [qrydata].[Group] & " AND Full_dur=""" & [YesOrNo] & """")

Thanks Mick, I tried your solution but the result for ItemID = 2010 & group 1 is not correct ( it must be 15 & 19 for both records but the result is 65,0 for both

Then your field Full_dur may be a Boolean value, Yes=-1 and No=0, so the Min-function in the first query returns the Yes row.
Solution: Change the Min- function to Max in the first query.

And a good thing is also then to remove the quotationmark in the two DLookUps.
.
AND Full_dur=""" & [YesOrNo] & """" to AND Full_dur=" & [YesOrNo]

you are right, after changing Min to Max it works fine.

The only way I could think of, is using VBA functions. One for each column.
Open a module in VBA editor and type the following:
Option Explicit 

Public Function Get_D_before_G(iItemID As Long, iGroup As Integer)
Dim bFlag1 As Boolean, bFlag2 As Boolean
Dim iD_before1 As Integer, iD_before2 As Integer
    With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Full_dur, D_before FROM qYourOriginalQuery WHERE ItemID = " & iItemID & " AND qYourOriginalQuery.Group = " & iGroup & ";", dbOpenDynaset)
        .MoveFirst
        bFlag1 = !Full_dur
        iD_before1 = !D_before
        .MoveNext
        bFlag2 = !Full_dur
        iD_before2 = !D_before
        Select Case True
            Case bFlag1 And bFlag2 'case 1: both are true
                Get_D_before_G = !D_before
            Case bFlag1 Or bFlag2  'case 2: this case excludes both are true, as this is the first case
                If bFlag1 Then
                    Get_D_before_G = !D_before
                Else
                    .MovePrevious
                    Get_D_before_G = !D_before
                End If
            Case Else 'case 3: both are false
                If iD_before1 < iD_before2 Then
                    Get_D_before_G = iD_before1
                Else
                    Get_D_before_G = iD_before2
                End If
        End Select
    End With
End Function

Public Function Get_D_after_G(iItemID As Long, iGroup As Integer)
Dim bFlag1 As Boolean, bFlag2 As Boolean
Dim iD_after1 As Integer, iD_after2 As Integer
    With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Full_dur, D_after FROM qYourOriginalQuery WHERE ItemID = " & iItemID & " AND qYourOriginalQuery.Group = " & iGroup & ";", dbOpenDynaset)
        .MoveFirst
        bFlag1 = !Full_dur
        iD_after1 = !D_after
        .MoveNext
        bFlag2 = !Full_dur
        iD_after2 = !D_after
        Select Case True
            Case bFlag1 And bFlag2 'case 1: both are true
                Get_D_after_G = !D_after
            Case bFlag1 Or bFlag2  'case 2: this case excludes both are true, as this is the first case
                If bFlag1 Then
                    Get_D_after_G = !D_after
                Else
                    .MovePrevious
                    Get_D_after_G = !D_after
                End If
            Case Else 'case 3: both are false
                If iD_after1 < iD_after2 Then
                    Get_D_after_G = iD_after1
                Else
                    Get_D_after_G = iD_after2
                End If
        End Select
    End With
End Function

Then add to your original query two new columns like this:
SELECT rest_of_your_columns, Get_D_before_G(ItemID, Group) AS D_before_G, Get_D_after_G(ItemID, Group) AS D_after_G     
FROM rest_of_your_query;

Important notes about this method:

Replace qYourOriginalQuery in the functions (there is 4 times) with the one you already have.
ItemID and Group field's type must be number. If not then the SELECT statements in the VBA functions need to change.
ItemID and Group values exist in pairs only as you state. That is, there are strictly 2 of them each time. If there are more or less of them, then this method will not work right.
This may not be quite effective when used with large sets of data
Maybe you should consider changing the name of the field Group as this is a reserved word and may cause you trouble.


It is working perfectly, thanks mints. I only test it & I'll review its details.
